# What is the structure of compressed scan data stream in JPEG, is it byte aligned?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

In scan data the following happens:

1. DC coefficient differential's magnitude bits are huffman encoded, these 4 bits SSSS are then followed by raw bits of the DC coefficient differential that can vary between 1 and 15 bits in length.
2. AC coefficients' zeros are run length encoded to create a 4 bit zero run-length with 4 magnitude information about the following non zero AC coefficient as RRRRSSSS. This RRRRSSSS is huffman encoded and followed by raw bits of nonzero AC cofficient if it exists.

Now what is not clear from any document are following:

1. Is huffman coded data for all cofficients *within an MCU* always aligned to byte boundary? If so then some bits after reading in raw bits of a coefficient shall be discarded.
2. Does compressed data for each succeeding MCU always start from a byte boundary?

If answer is yes to both above then data of an MCU is tightly packed, and data for a scan (interleaved or not) is also tightly packed, no bits wasted.

Another confusion, since a few markers like e.g RSTn can actually occur within scan data:

3. Do markers occur only at byte boundaries? If not then some bits are following raw bits are being wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is huffman coded data for all cofficients within an MCU always aligned to byte boundary? If so then some bits after reading in raw bits of a coefficient shall be discarded.

No.

> Does compressed data for each succeeding MCU always start from a byte boundary?
> If answer is yes to both above then data of an MCU is tightly packed, and data for a scan (interleaved or not) is also tightly packed, no bits wasted.

No.

> Another confusion, since a few markers like e.g RSTn can actually occur within scan data:
>
> Do markers occur only at byte boundaries? If not then some bits are following raw bits are being wasted.

Yes. If the stream is compressed with restart markers, it is likely that there will be wasted bits before the marker.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you have reference to these in documentation (e g ITU T.81) as well? It will make things easier for me.

Comment: If there are wasted bits (maybe they are all 1s, don't know), won't it clash with the huffman table? That is to say, are these padding bits such that they are not part of any huffman code?

Comment: Besides restart marker there are other markers including the end of image marker, I assume that all markers always are bye aligned

Comment: If there are wasted bits before marker (maybe they are all 1s, don't know), won't it clash with the huffman table? That is to say, are these padding bits such that they are not part of any huffman code?

Comment: They are just ignored.

Comment: All right, I shall fill that space with 1s. Do you know of a reference from the documentation e.g from ITU T.81 where it says that the MCUs are tightly packed? I shall help in my notes.

Comment: 'No' is based on what?